# MVC3 Ajax displayin all values in array

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I get my values from  my action control but i wanna show all my values. How to use for loop or foreach in ajax to show array all of elements ?

Here is my script

> $.ajax({
>               type: "get", url: "Home/Oku", data: {}, dataType: "json",
>               success: function (data) {
>                   for (var i = 0; i< data.length; i++) {
>                       $("img#myimage").attr("src", data[i])
>                       i++;
>                   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear what you are trying to do. It is not clear what format your controller action uses to return the data. From the code you have shown I can assume that it returns an array of strings. And then I suppose that those strings represent urls to some images because you seem to be attempting to assign them to the src attribute of an img tag. Except that you are using an id selector and always overwriting the same img tag for each element.

If you want to have multiple images, then you could create them dynamically. Start by creating an empty placeholder:

```
<div id="images"></div>
```

and then:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Home/Oku', 
    type: 'GET', 
    success: function (data) {
        var images = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            images = images + '<div><img src="' + data[i] + '" /></div>';
        }
        $('#images').html(images);
    }
});
```

This assumes that your controller action returns a JSON encoded array of strings representing urls for the images:

```
public ActionResult Oku()
{
    var imageUrls = new[] 
    { 
        "http://example.com/foo.jpg", 
        "http://example.com/bar.jpg" 
    };
    return Json(imageUrls, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```